# Python multiple possibilities in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python and I have an assignment to print month names with corresponding numbers.

How can I make an `if` statement with multiple conditions so I don't need to make twelve of them?

Normally it would be :

```
if month == 1
   print(one) # one = January
```

Can I make it something like :

```
if month == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
   print [one,two.three, etc.]
```

I tried it and it does not work, but I am wondering if it is possible?

Comment: `if month in [1,2,3,4,5,6]` better to use a map though

Comment: you want to print a corresponding value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Dictionary

```
months = {1:"Jan", 2:"Feb", 3:"March" ... and so on}

if inputMonth in months:
   print(months[inputMonth])
```

or you can use List

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "March"... ]
inputMonth = 1
if inputMonth in range(0,13):
   print(months[inputMonth-1])
```

Comment: `Map` isn't a python concept ;)

Comment: Had to change it a bit, but that is what I was talking about! Thank you mate!
month = ["January", "February" , "March", "April", "May", \
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ]
inputMonth = int(input("Input a number of month: "))
if inputMonth in range(0,13):
    print(month[inputMonth-1])

Comment: @BuggyBuggy oh good idea i didn't get that `range(0,13)` thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'd better save that in a dict, to get mappings `month index -> month name`

```
months = {1: "January", 2: "February"}
month = 1
if month in months:
    print(months[month])
```

Or with `calendar`

```
import calendar
month = 1
if month in range(13):
    print(calendar.month_name[month])
```